# GLPK variable not defined

Tags: glpk

I have the following model.

```
param nbpdt;
set J;
set I;
param p{i in I, j in J};
var S, integer, >=0;
var O, integer, >=0;
var E, integer, >=0;
#objectif
minimize surface: sum{i in I} p[i,1]-(p[i,2] * S)-(p[i,3] * O)-(p[i,4] * E);
```

When i try to run it this error comes :

```
pv.mod:9: i not defined
Context:  ; minimize surface : sum { i in I } p [ i , 1 ] - ( p [ i ,
```

Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum operator has the same operator precedence as the plus and the minus operator.

So in your term

```
sum{i in I} p[i,1] - (p[i,2] * S)
```

*sum* is only applied to *p[i,1]* and not to the following term. Just add parentheses as needed, e.g.

```
sum{i in I} ( p[i,1] - (p[i,2] * S) )
```